# jqgrid within a column of outer jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have to show a jqgrid within each row of another jqgrid. In the second column of the outer jqgrid, I need to show a jqgrid for each row. These inner jqgrids (subgrids) can have multiple rows and columns based on the data coming from the business model. If multiple rows in subgrids, I may have to show a "Select All" checkbox for each subgrid and then get the selected records (IDs) to save to database. Any input will help.

[Grid Requirement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdCL5.jpg)

Comment: The image you have attached does not help much. Can you explain a bit more on what you have done so far and is it an issue if you include a new grid initialisation script on each row with some kind of expand button. or just after loading main grid.

Comment: @Farrukh, I am new to jqgrid and have not done much on it. I need to place a subgrid in the second column in each row. The outer grid will have only two columns.

Comment: In your main grid the results in 2nd column should be the grid containers then you pick them up with a class attribute and load all grids individually by initialising them after loading first grid. Make sense?

Comment: Thank you @Farrukh.